# Where is the config file for the man command?

Tags: configuration, command, man

since I changed my keyboard layout to Colemak I want to change all my system shortcuts appropriately.
Has anyone a good idea where to change the configs globally or where the config for the man command is ?

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: What Unix are you using exactly? The `man` command works differently depending on the Unix you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man man
...
General options
       -C file, --config-file=file
              Use this user configuration file rather than the default of ~/.manpath.
...
FILES
       /etc/man_db.conf
              man-db configuration file.

       /usr/share/man
              A global manual page hierarchy.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :D Definitely a case of rtfm... my bad ^-^